# Setting up Database connection in .Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm battling to find resources on how to setup a database connection string in ASP.net core. I have added the connection string to the appsettings.json file below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MTDatabase": "Server=ss-demo-7-sep112;Database=MTDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

but need to find a way to access this connection string in my generic repositry. which is found in a seperate project to my .net core app where it contains all Data Access Layer stuff. Below is my generic repositry where I am trying to get my connection string

```
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

namespace HaldanMT.DAL
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {

        protected ObjectContext _context;
        protected ObjectSet<T> _objectSet { get; set; }

        public GenericRepository(string connectionName = "MTDatabase")
        {
            _context = new ObjectContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString);
            _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I have already made reference to this DAL project in my .net core project. The project fails when trying to connect to the DB, the exception is `System.NullReferenceException` Object reference not set to an instance of an object for the `ConnectionString`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to set up EF6 or EF Core? The above code looks like ASP.NET 4.5 / EF6. also do you target .NET Core or just ASP.NET Core on full .NET Framework? Its a huge difference. .NET Core and .NET Framework are runtimes, ASP.NET Core is just a webstack, which runs on both. EF6 however only runs on full .NET Framework

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

This is the link where the use of JSON as connection string is mentioned.
it will be like this

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")).
```

Just follow the tutorial will help you.